# Add field to user meta table in database when link is clicked

Tags: posts, custom-field, database, users

I am working on function that enables registered users on my site to bookmark posts. I have searched for plugins but none seemed to do the job properly.

I have a page where users can see their info like name, email, password and so on. I want a list of posts they have bookmarked. This should be done by clicking on a link in the post, which then saves the url or a link to the post in the database.

The code for getting the url of the post:

```
function curPageURL() {
$pageURL = 'http';
 if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
  $pageURL .= "://";
 if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
 $pageURL .=     
 $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 } else {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 }
 return $pageURL;
 }
```

Now i have the url in a variable. But how i can store this url in a field for the current user?

I was thinking about inserting a field in user table. But I'm not quite sure how and if this is the best way to go about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I would store the post IDs (as opposed to URLs). Something like:

```
function wpse_143643_add_user_bookmark() {
    if ( ! empty( $_GET['bookmark'] ) && is_singular() && is_user_logged_in() ) {
        if ( ! $bookmarks = get_user_meta( $user_id = get_current_user_id(), 'bookmarks', true ) )
            $bookmarks = array();

        $bookmarks[] = get_queried_object_id();
        $bookmarks = array_unique( $bookmarks );

        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'bookmarks', $bookmarks );
    }
}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpse_143643_add_user_bookmark' );
```

So a link like `http://example.com/my-post/?bookmark=true` will add `my-post` to the current user's bookmarks.

And to display the list of bookmarks:

```
if ( $bookmarks = get_user_meta( $user_id = get_current_user_id(), 'bookmarks', true ) ) {
    $posts = get_posts(
        array(
            'post__in' => $bookmarks,
        )   
    );

    $list = '<ul class="bookmarks">';
    foreach ( $posts as $_post )
        $list .= '<li><a href="' . get_permalink( $_post->ID ) . '">' . get_the_title( $_post->ID ) . '</a></li>';
    $list .= '</ul>';

    echo $list;
}
```

Comment: Good point, haven't even thought about using the post id. This makes more sense. How would I go about running this function when a user clicks on a link?

Comment: Running which function? The adding of the bookmark or the listing of the bookmarks?

Comment: Sorry i didn't make myself clear. The adding of the bookmark, e.g. when the user clicks on "Bookmark this" link/button.

Comment: That's the first code snippet. I would wrap it in a function and hook it to the `template_redirect` action. See my revision.

Comment: Hmm i must have missed something. When i use `http://example.com/my-post/?bookmark=true` and try to display it nothing shows.

Comment: Are you sure you're visiting a valid & published post? And that you're signed in? And where have you added the second code snippet that displays the bookmarks?

Comment: I am logged in and i can see in my database that the post id is getting stored. The posts in question are custom post types if that should make any difference. I am using the second snippet on a different page but that shouldn't make any difference. I can't figure out it doesn't return anything.

Comment: Stupid me, there were 2 underscores in `post_in`. Thank you very much for providing code. I'll mark your answer as correct!

Comment: Ok got another problem, wasn't paying enough attention. Seems that `?bookmark=true` doesn't store the right post in the database. When I use the function on a new user it saves 4 posts at once and no of them is the right one?